# .Net Core project not responding on high traffic in iis

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc

project is written in ASP .Net Core V2.2 .
website stops responding when traffic gets high, and then should restart website in IIS.
in this project we have some async functions and some of them run in parallel that no need to wait for them.
how can detect the problem?
is it bug? or is related to iis settings?
which tool can help to find out problem?

Comment: Learn how to use a performance profiler, or dump analysis to locate the cause. You can assume that 99% of such issues are caused by your own code or third party dependencies, as writing the right code and embrace the async model is never easy. You shouldn't waste time trying IIS settings before you know the cause.

Comment: Async != parallel. You're likely leaking memory and potentially exhausting the thread pool. If you want to background something, use an actual background process, like a hosted service or an entirely different process. It's virtually always wrong to not await something completely (you might not await it inline, but it should be awaited as some point in the scope).